# Change desktop Google Drive account without permission to access old account

Tags: passwords, desktop, google-drive-api, accounts

I used my home computer for desktop Google Drive with my work email account. Once I left the company, they changed the password on the account. I would now like to use Google Drive desktop with my personal email address. I am not able to access preferences to disable the old account since I don't know the new password they established for that account. How can I disable desktop Drive with that account and initiate desktop Drive with my personal account, without knowing the password for the work account?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Drive on a Mac you need to delete some files in order to re-sign in.

Close Google Drive by clicking on the icon in the menu bar and choosing Quit Google Drive. There is no need to uninstall the app.

In your home folder (/Users/username/) go to Library/Preferences/ and delete two files:
com.google.GoogleDrive.plist
com.google.GoogleDrive.plist.lockfile

Then navigate to another folder in your home folder, Library/Application Support/Google/Drive/ and delete all the files and folders.

Now restart Google Drive and you will be able to sign in with your personal account.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as I have had experienced, going this way, you lose at least all files that were pending synchronization by this point.

So at least you need to save all your not-synchronized-yet files and re-move them to Google Disk folder later.

Another example of home many pain free service could supply.